# How to reference a View in another XML without including it?

Tags: android, xml, include

My code currently requires a reference to a ListView in another XML file and activity. I have tried using the include keyword as so:

```
<include layout="@layout/cleareditems"/>
```

However, when I do this it merges the two layouts and you can see everything in clearedItems. What would I do just to reference that View and change it?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to include one particular View of another layout?

Comment: Please explain clearly, whether you want a particular view of another layout or something else.

Comment: I would like to have my listview from the other xml not be visible at all. I wo;uld just like to reference it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example

```
<PATH_TO_YOUR_CLASS.YOUR_CLASS
    android:id="@+id/search"//we give some name to it
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and you should use merge tag, so the layout are not duplicated

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
//YOUR CUSTOM VIEW ELEMENTS, in this case its called search from above
</merge>
```